The QR decomposition of upper Hessenberg matrix has the property that the $i+1,i$-th elements of $RQ$ are nonzero
The problem is:Let $A$ be a $n*n$ real invertible upper Hessenberg matrix and for all $i$, we have $a_{i+1,i}\neq 0$, let the $QR$ decomposition of it be $A=QR$, then I want to prove that $(RQ)_{i+1,i}\neq 0$ for all $i$
here is my attempt, I have proved that if the diagonal elements of the uppertriangular matrix $R=[r_{ij}]$ is all nonnegative, and let $A=[a_{ij}]$, then we have $r_{kk}\geq |a_{k+1,k}|$, this can be proved by using Givens rotation and induction,then what should we do?, from this we know that $Q$ is also upper Hessenberg, then what should we do?
Edit:because $Q$ is upper Hessenberg, hence the $(RQ)_{i+1,i}$ is $r_{ii}q_{(i-1),i}$, if this is zero, then if $r_{ii}=0$, then the $det$ is zero, which contradicts that $A^{-1}$ exists, but what about $q_{(i-1),i}=0$?
